# What is the output for this sequential circuit?

Tags: analysis

[image: OP image]

For this sequential circuit
are the outputs "next state function" for q1 and q0?

$$D1 = (Q1)Y' + (Q0)Y' $$
$$J0 = Y'(Q1)' + Y((Q1)'+(Q0)')$$
$$K0 = Y$$
$$Q1 = D1$$
$$Q0 = (J0)(Q0)'+(K0)'(Q0)$$

Comment: Are you sure the circuit is drawn correctly?

Comment: I think I can see an error too

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted this question on my account. The picture is straight out of a textbook, what is the error in the drawing?

Comment: And what textbook is it from and what does the textbook say it does? Why should we not be priveleged with the information you have when you would like this site to answer a question about its functionality

Comment: Logic and computer design fundamentals custom edition. The task is to perform the analysis of the sequential circuit. I already have done it for present states, but this drawing was missing an output that I would normally see, So I was wondering if the outputs are simply the next states from q1 and q0. So my state table is half-way complete

Comment: @Theran, for your #5, is that the output for the entire circuit?

Comment: I have edited my answer, how do I determine Q0?

Comment: @Aaron, recall how a D flip-flop behaves: On the rising edge of the clock, whatever value is at the D input becomes the Q output, and the Q output stays the same until the next rising edge. Thus, whatever is at the D inputs just prior to the clock edge is the next state of the Q outputs.

Comment: It would be normal to name the authors too. I'm guessing this is Mano & Kime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it systematically:

1. Write the boolean equations for D1, J0, and K0
2. Simplify those equations to make life easier.
3. Replace the JK flip flop with an equivalent input to a D flip-flop. Let's call the input of that FF D0.
4. Simplify the equations a little more.
5. The next state is just D0 and D1.